# Bootstrap datePicker(Months and years only) wont show properly

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, monthcalendar

I found a code that will provide a datepicker input box which allow to choose only month and year, but the output did show the correct date i've chose, but still the select box still showing the date.

**Pict 1** is the condition before I choose any date
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl6KT.png

**Pict 2** is the condition after I choose any date
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwS9e.png

```
<div class='input-group date datepicker' id='table'>
    <input type='text' name="tgl" class="form-control" />
         <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
             </span>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript

```
$('#table').datepicker({
    format: 'MM/yyyy', 
    icons: {
        time: 'fa fa-time',
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-remove'
    }
});
```

Im sure i did import the bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add the following properties to your `datepicker` initialization:

```js
startView: "months",
minViewMode: "months"
```

Working example:

```js
$('#table').datepicker({
  format: 'MM/yyyy',
  icons: {
    time: 'fa fa-time',
    date: 'fa fa-calendar',
    up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
    down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
    previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
    next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
    today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
    clear: 'fa fa-trash',
    close: 'fa fa-remove'
  },
  startView: "months",
  minViewMode: "months"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='input-group date datepicker' id='table'>
  <input type='text' name="tgl" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked!! Thank you ^^

Comment: @CarinaNatalia glad it helped :)